# How to debug error in process sentinel?

Tags: magit, dired, debugging, doom

I've recently switched to `doom` emacs, and for the most part it's working great.

However, when I'm looking at a folder in `dired-mode`, if I copy a file using `C` the file is copied but `*Messages*` contains the following:

```
error in process sentinel: vc-exec-after: Unexpected process state
error in process sentinel: Unexpected process state No library
simple.el in search path
```

More significant is that it leaves a `.git/index.lock` which I need to manually delete.

I have the following questions:

1. How can this issue be investigated?
2. How can this specific issue be fixed?
3. How can the 'vc' aspect of dired be disabled?

The last point is because I would like to use `magit` exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to 1., I'm not sure about Doom Emacs, but on GNU Emacs you could navigate to lisp/vc/vc-dispatcher.el, move pointer to `(defun vc-exec-after (code) ...` and invoke `C-u C-M-x` to invoke `eval-defun`. Move cursor to first line, add a breakpoint `edebug-set-breakpoint`, and run the code/command again to use Edebug to step through the code.

Also, maybe you can get a hint from invoking `toggle-debug-on-error`. It should show a minibuffer with error and stack trace when errors occur anywhere in the elisp code paths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I did find the breakpoint, and then noticed the following variable `diff-hl-dired-ignored-backends`.  I added `Git` to this - and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to 3, there is a variable that specifies a list of backends to ignore:

> Documentation
>
> VC backends to ignore.
>
> The directories registered to one of these backends won't have status indicators.

Adding the following in `.doom.d/config.el` adds `Git` to the list of ignored backends:

```
(after! dired
  (setq diff-hl-dired-ignored-backends (append
                                        '((Git) (RCS)))))
```